# How to sort / compare booleans in Lua

Tags: lua

How to compare / sort boolean values in Lua? Assume the "standard" ordering `true` > `false`.

```
local first = true
local second = false

first > second

stdin:1: attempt to compare two boolean values
stack traceback:
      stdin:1: in main chunk
      [C]: in ?
```

Comment: You answered your own question the same minute that you asked it. Posting as a tutorial? Why?

Comment: @Brian answering your own question is accepted, and even encouraged by SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer there's even a checkbox to add an answer right at the page where you create the question.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I never noticed the checkbox. I’d only suggest, then, a clarification of the post title: your answer is relevant for defining a sorting comparator, but for just comparing two bools for equality (`first == second`), I would just convert each to a string using `tostring` and then comapre. Anyway, thanks for the SO policy clarification.

Comment: Why do you want to compare booleans for order?

Comment: @Brian thanks. I tried to edit the post to make it more clearer.

Comment: @lhf I want to compare booleans in order to sort tables containing them. For example, having a big array of elements, sort by a boolean attribute first, then sort by a number attribute (secondary). Standard tuple sorting where one of the parameters is a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Booleans cannot be compared for order.

But if you insist, try this:

```
debug.setmetatable(true,{
    __lt = function (x,y) return (not x) and y end
})

print("false < false", false < false)
print("false < true",  false < true)
print("true  < false", true  < false)
print("true  < true",  true  < true)
```

Comment: Nice. This adds a comparison function to all booleans globally if I get it correctly. The downside is that you should have `debug.setmetatable` available.

Answer (score 1):

Since both operands are booleans, you can use standard boolean techniques:

```
first or not second  -- first >= second
first and not second  --  first > second
```

Example:

```
my_table = {
  { name = "Max", strong = true },
  { name = "Ray", strong = false },
  { name = "Sam", strong = true }
}
table.sort(my_table, function(a, b)
  return a.strong or not b.strong
end)
```

The version with `>=` `a or not b` is more performant for sorting because it would return `true` for more boolean pairs, and would thus incur fewer "element swap" operations during sort.